# Chart.js. Offset between stacked bars

Tags: charts, bar-chart, stacked-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I need to add offset between stacked bars like it is on the
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQz1M.png).

I've read documentations and rummaged in the source files, but found nothing.
Maybe someone has encountered such a feature or with such plugin.
My configurations is just copy of this sample https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/samples/bar/stacked.md

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's just base setup. I attached link code example.